# Java String parsing, What is faster? Regex or String methods?

Tags: java, regex

I'm facing a dilemma.
I'm parsing a string and can either do

```
s.matches(regex)
```

or I can do

```
s.startsWith(..) && s.endsWith(..)
```

As you already realize, its not a complicated regexp, and both situations will work.
The idea is, the string may be very long (hundreds of chars), so I wish to maximize efficiency.
What works how and better suits the issue?

Comment: Regex is slower as it needs regex compilation

Comment: When I see questions like "what is faster?" I always think "well just benchmark it and check it out yourself".

Comment: you could write the benchmarks in about 5 minutes flat

Comment: remember to cache your regex

Comment: Why don't you time the execution of both and tell us the timings?

Comment: Do a little benchmark with System.currentTimeMillis() and you will know. I bet that startsWith and endWith will be 10 times faster for really big strings :)

Comment: Regex is *faster* if the regex is precompiled.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a really rather crude *benchmark* to give you an idea. Adapt it to your use cases to give you more relevant results.

#### TL;DR

- `startsWith()` and `endsWith()` are much faster

---

## Detailed results

Results after 1 000 000 runs:

```
- Uncompiled pattern:        1091 ms
- Compiled pattern:          745 ms
- startsWith() / endsWith(): 24 ms
```

```
public class TestRegex {

    String regex = "^start.*end$";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    
    String start = "start";
    String end = "end";
    String search = start + "fewbjlhfgljghfadsjhfdsaglfdhjgahfgfjkhgfdkhjsagafdskghjafdkhjgfadskhjgfdsakhjgfdaskhjgafdskjhgafdsjhkgfads" + end;
    
    int runs = 1000000;

    @Test
    public final void test() {
        // Init run
        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
            search.matches(regex);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
            p.matcher(search).matches();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
            search.startsWith(start);
            search.endsWith(end);
        }


        // Timed run
        Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
            search.matches(regex);
        }
        System.out.println(s.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        s.reset();
        
        s.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
            p.matcher(search).matches();
        }
        System.out.println(s.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        s.reset();
        
        s.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
            search.startsWith(start);
            search.endsWith(end);
        }
        System.out.println(s.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 The JIT will replace certain String methods with highly optimized assembler code; sometimes, they can be replaced with a single CPU opcode.

Answer (score 5):

Note that both methods may report different results in cases where the string expeted at the end is a suffix of the start string:

```
^start.*art$
```

will not match

```
"start"
```

while

```
"start".startsWith("start") && "start".endsWith("art")
```

will be true.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the difference is there and noticeable for small strings as well.
Having a compiled version of the regex using a pattern does make some enhancements, but no doubt, its the worst idea when the match is easy.

Thanks everyone.